# clustered index and dataload in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

If a source table has a clustered index on the primary key, will the select * from table order by that primary key field without having to stipulate the order by in the query for that field?

My second question is does SSIS load a table that has a clustered index on the source table primary key exactly the same order in the destination?

I just want to make sure my identity keys that I create for the surrogate key based on the primarykey/business key always enters in the right order in the source and also in the destination

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

SQL has zero inherent order unless explicitly specified in the `ORDER BY` clause of your query.

There are no guarantee's data will be ordered by the clustered index when selected.  You can run a query 100 times with no `ORDER BY` -- and it comes out the same, but there's no promise the next time it will be in that order.

If you want SSIS to push data between tables in a particular order, you must specify a source query with an `ORDER BY` clause in your data flow.

Comment: So say if i order by the source in the dataflow by that primary key,  will the results always be in the correct order in the destination? For certain 100% of the time? Thank you